# Extracting integer ranges separated with hyphen

Tags: c#, regex, split

I try to filter some strings I streamed for some useful information in C#.
I got two possible string structures:

```
string examplestring1 = "from - to (mm) no. 1\r\n\r\nna 570 - 590\r\n60 18.12.20\r\nna 5390 - 5410\r\n60 18.12.20\r\nna 11380 - 11390 60 18.12.20\r\nPage 1/1";
string examplestring2 = "e ne 570 - 590 ne 5390 - 5410 ne 11380 - 11390 e";
```

I'd like to get an array or a List of strings in the format of "xxx - xxx". Like:

```
string[] example = new string[]{"570 - 590","5390 - 5410","11380 - 11390"};
```

I tried to use Regex:

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
numbers.AddRange(Regex.Split(examplestring2, @"\D+"));
```

At least I get a list only containg the numbers. But that doesn't work out for examplestring1 since there is date within.
Also I tried to play around with Regex pattern. But things like following does not work.

```
Regex.Split(examplestring1, @"\D+" + " - " + @"\D+");
```

I'd be grateful for a solution or at least some hint how to solve that matter.

Comment: Does something like `/^d+(\-d+\-d+)?$/i` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d+\s*-\s*\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%5Cs*-%5Cs*%5Cd%2B&i=from%20-%20to%20%28mm%29%20no.%201%0D%0A%0D%0Ana%20570%20-%20590%0D%0A60%2018.12.20%0D%0Ana%205390%20-%205410%0D%0A60%2018.12.20%0D%0Ana%2011380%20-%2011390%2060%2018.12.20%0D%0APage%201%2F1%0D%0Ae%20ne%20570%20-%20590%20ne%205390%20-%205410%20ne%2011380%20-%2011390%20e). If there must be a single regular space on both ends of the `-`, you can use `\d+ - \d+` regex.

If you want to match any `-`, you can use `[\p{Pd}\xAD]` instead of `-`.

Note that `\d` in .NET matches any Unicode digits, to only match ASCII digits, use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option: `Regex.Matches(text, @"\d+\s*-\s*\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`.

Comment: I think normal numbers should be supported as well.

Comment: @LajosArpad See the title: *Extracting integer ranges separated with hyphen*. Let OP confirm.

Comment: This is why I think digit-only values should also be supported: "At least I get a list only containg the numbers. But that doesn't work out for examplestring1 since there is date within."